# Repeating letters in a string output after removing spaces

Tags: c++

I'm trying to remove all spaces from a string. I wrote code, it removes spaces, but in the end it rewrites last couple letters depending on how many spaces it removed. For example in the code below, output is: `randomteststringng`.

Any help?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    string txtname = "random test string";
    remove(txtname.begin(),txtname.end(),' ');
    
    cout<<txtname;
    
    return 0;
    
}
```

Comment: `std::remove()` does not actually **remove** anything, it just **moves** the matching items to the end of the specified range (ie, imagine what happens if you `remove()` items from a fixed-sized array - they *can't* actually be removed). `remove()` returns an iterator to the "removed" items, ie the new `end` of the range. To actually **remove** the items completely, you need to `erase()` the range of "removed" items between the "new" `end` and the "old" `end`, eg: `auto iter = remove(txtname.begin(), txtname.end(), ' '); txtname.erase(iter, txtname.end());`

Comment: Also, just FYI, you can't get `"randomteststringng  "` by removing spaces from `"random test string"`, it should be `"randomteststring  "` instead, since `std::remove()` will not change the string's size.